# ternary operation in order by Firebase Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, conditional-operator

I have a collection with documents in Firebase with the following fields

`Id`,`Description`,`amount`,`price`

This collection over time contains many documents stored.

But now a new column has been added, so that it can be sorted by this column.

`Id`,`Description`,`amount`,`price`,`Total`

When doing the query with the order by, it shows me the information correctly but only of the new documents.

Previous documents that do not have the column `Total`, are not shown.

```
this.db.collection('OrderDet', ref => ref.where("Id", "==", uid).orderby("Total","asc"));
```

How can I make the query show me all of the documents, including those that do not have the column `Total`

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, what you're seeing is expected behavior.

From the Firestore Documentation [Ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) - which states

> An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given fields.
> The result set will not include documents that do not contain the
> given fields.

So the solution is to either remove the `orderBy` clause *or* leave the orderBy clause in and ensure all documents contain the `Total` field with a zero (0) balance (value).

You could just craft a small section of code to add that field to old documents.

Also, you can load the data you want with no `orderBy` and sort in code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I cannot remove the Order by clause, because it is a client requirement.

Comment: then, I will try to make a code that updates the old documents as you are recommending me